# How to create django model objects where one of the field is datetime

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I have a model

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
   fixture_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                                    
   league_id =models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                      
   event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I am trying to create object from this model. I am using Postgresql and in settings.py activated USE_TZ = True

```
fixt = Fixture.objects.create(fixture_id = fixture_id,league_id_id = league_id,event_date=event_date, event_timestamp = event_timestamp)
```

while i am trying to create object get the folowing traceback

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'event_date' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be this will help you

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
   fixture_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                                    
   league_id =models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                      
   event_date =models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
   event_timestamp =models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I want to store in event_timestamp value which isnt auto_now = True